# Prove that $1/x^2$ diverges to infinity as $ x\to 0$, but $1/x$ does not diverge to infinity as $x\to 0$.

Tags: real-analysis

> $f(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to c$, written $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=\infty$, if for every
>   $α\in\Bbb R$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for every $x\in A$ satisfying
>   $0 < |x − c| < \delta$, one has $f(x) > α$.

This is the definition I can use for this, but I don't see how I would be able to prove this. 
Any help?

Comment: The main point is that $x$ can approach 0 from the left or the right, in which case $1/x$ becomes arbitrarily large and positive or large and negative (it tends to both $\pm \infty$), while $1/x^2$ is always positive around 0, so it goes to $\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ be given. Take $\delta >0$ such that ${1 \over {\delta}}>\sqrt{\alpha}$, then if $0<|x|<\delta$:

${1 \over x^2}={1 \over |x|^2}>{1 \over \delta ^2}>\alpha$, which completes the proof.

The problem with $1/x$ is that $1/x \to +\infty$ when $x\to 0^+$ but $1/x \to -\infty$ when $x \to 0^-$.

Comment: thank you .so for 1/x id do the same by proving the same way  you did for 1/x^2?

Comment: You can do something similar to prove that $1/x \to +\infty$ when $x \to 0^+$, that is when $x$ is positive. However $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}{1 \over x}$ does not exist, since the function tends to $+\infty$ when $x$ approaches $0$ from the right and to $-\infty$ when $x$ approaches $0$ from the left.